# Database Setup: Recording Delta or Total Value

Tags: sql, database-design

I am in charge of creating a database for recording production data.(I have no formal experience in databases or SQL) Using Microsoft SQL

I can think of 2 different ways to structure our data that we record.
   1: I can record the current value of totalizer for each material
   2: I can record the amount produced from last record.

Some background, we will be recording information every minute to track production and amount of each material used in the mix.

We have reports that print out showing how much material and mix was produced in a given day, over a span of days.

I guess my question boils down to is it faster to sum values in a query or search for the max value associated with the material / mix?

Comment: Your ask is not much clear to me,can you please elaborate

Comment: Words like "totalizer" and "mix" and "material" don't mean anything unless you explain the complete business context of the data.

Comment: Sorry, ok lets assume I'm making lemonade, I have 3 ingredients, water sugar, lemon juice. my mix would be lemonade.  I would like to know the best way to track what ingredients and how much were used. but I have to assume Lemonade can be made multiple times a day, and not necessary back to back. and Water could be in more than 1 mix. the "totalizer" I talk about totals up the amount of materials used during a mix, and is reset when a mix is changed or the machine is stopped. so I can't necessarily look for the highest total of water, because the total will be reset multiple times over the day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will certainly be faster to find the quantity at any given point in time if the record contains the net quantity. Then when you want to find the quantity, you just read one record -- the latest record or the record for the appropriate date and time -- and pick off the quantity. If you stored deltas, then you would have to sum them all up from day zero.

On the other hand, if there are multiple independent source of change, and/or if it is possible for changes to be cancelled or reversed, then storing the "current amount" becomes a problem. What happens if transactions arrive out of order, or if older transactions are modified or deleted?

The classic example of this is the bank account balance. Deposits and withdrawals can come from multiple sources at unpredictable times. We often want to post a transaction out of sequence. An older transaction may be cancelled.

So for example:

Jan 1: Account opened with $1,000. Balance = $1,000.

Jan 2: Deposit of $300. Balance = $1300.

Jan 3: Withdrawal of $200. Balance = $1100.

Jan 4: Check used for Jan 2 deposit bounces. Reverse deposit. So the balance on Jan 2 is changed to $1000. But what about the balance on Jan 3? We have to update it to $800.

In real life, there could have been a long series of transactions occurring after the bounced check. If we stored the final balance in every record, every one of those records would have to be updated.

Transactions often have an effective date that is different than the date they were entered into the system. So we will routinely find that transactions have to be inserted in the sequence before existing transactions, and then all following transactions would have to be updated.

Now maybe your lemonade stand is a different kind of process. If we add water to a bowl, we may well be saying, "add enough water to bring it up to the 'full' mark" rather than "add 4 liters". If that's the case -- if in most cases what the user knows and would enter into the computer is the new total quantity rather than the delta -- then it makes sense that what you would enter is the total quantity, and if you care about the delta, you calculate it. But if what the user knows is the delta, then they should enter the delta and you should carry the delta, and calculate the quantity.

Yes, there's the problem that if all you store is deltas, then calculating the net quantity requires totaling all the records since day zero. If the number of records is modest, this may be perfectly acceptable. If not, something I sometimes do is keep "total records" with the running total as of some date. Then to get the current quantity I find the latest total record and then add the transaction amounts since that date. It's extra pain to code but dramatically improves performance.